# Android to Android chat with socket when connected to same wifi

Tags: android, client, chat, serversocket

I want to make application in which two devices which are connected to same Wifi router can detect first which users are connected to this router this after click they can communicate with each other I need just steps to do this I am trying to this since many days worked on some `TCP` and `UDP` chat but got nothing I don't understand the way guide me steps so could be help full for me.
I tried this code many other searched on google
https://github.com/androidsrc/SocketClient

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this: https://github.com/udark/underdark-android/

This work with TCP and UPD both and its working fine. Some application already on the market. Also, you can visit this site for more details: http://underdark.io/